# Command can not be found

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command

I have this code

```
#!/bin/bash
read num
sum=0
i=1
while [$i -le $num]; do
    let sum=$sum+1
    let i=$i+1
done
echo $sum
```

I am getting the error ./test: line 5: [1: command not found , but I am not sure what part of this is wrong and can not be found.

Comment: Spaces are important. `[$i` needs to be `[ $i` and `$num]` needs to be `$num ]`.

Comment: Does Everything need spaces on both sides?

Comment: Define "everything". Commands do. `echo "foo"` is not the same command as `echo"foo"` clearly. `[` is no different. It happens to be a shell built-in but it is also a command (see `type -p [`). `]` is the closing syntax marker and also needs to be on its own to be seen, yes.

Comment: Yes, `[` is a command, and it demands that `]` is it's last (space-delimited) argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use arithmetic expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This function does safe read of a number
read_number ()
{
    read x

    # Check for an actual number
    case "$x" in ""|*[^0-9]*) echo "Not a number" >&2; exit 1;; esac

    # Consider base 10
    echo "$((10#$x))"
}

num=$(read_number)

sum=0
i=1
while ((i <= num)); do
    ((sum++, i++))
done
echo $sum
```

Comment: You should also check that `num` is an actual number. Don't use user input without sanitizing it: in this case, your code is subject to arbitrary code injection.

Comment: And to avoid another pitfall: `while ((i<=10#$num))`, just in case a user enters something like `09`.